# Importing external CRM data with new households/accounts joins

Tags: data-loader, import

Is there a best practice / simplified methodology for importing bulk records from an external CRM when there are new intricate household and account joins?

I have looked into dataloader.io, but what I am still unsure about is how the process works in the background.

Eg:

1) If a .csv file containing names with a column indicating who is their spouse, must the spouse always follow after the insertion of the original person (else the lookup will return null?)

2) If an account and or household doesn't already exist (IE: have an ID), is there a methodology for automatically creating ID's for those relationships from the .csv when it is imported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are importing data from External System, so create `External Id` field in Salesforce object (Account).

You should prepare the related data in the .csv format.

All the records can be imported based on External Id field and relationship can be maintained in Salesforce.

In the Dataloader, use `upsert` operation to map Salesforce `External Id` with the .csv column.

Note that, Parent records will be loaded first, followed by child records.

Comment: Thanks Santanu. The issue is the accounts need to be created dynamically. IE: Importing a contact record may (or may not) create an associated Account, and then later that individual may (or may not) be joined to a household. So are you suggesting to make a quasi-primary key for each csv line, and then map each line of the csv through a quasi-foreign key (based on the primary keys?)